# How to Pass Sqlite Values in a view

Tags: iphone

How to pass sqlite data in a view .I want to display sqlite data in a view controller,with paging enabled.I have a big amount of data in database,that i want to display in many pages.How to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use Table Views, should have googled about this topic, anyways these 2 are pretty useful

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/08/how-to-use-sqlite-with-uitableview-in-iphone-sdk/

Comment: but i need to display like a book reader,with paging etc.is it possible to do it in a tableview?

Comment: I guess you can add a separate footer saying "more" which takes you to the remaining data. I'm not very sure about this.

Similar topic is discussed here , 3rd post has been useful for some, hope you find a solution :
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html